# CSS Scale causes jagged edges when transitioning

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with a preloader I have created.
It is just a simple mask effect which looks like this:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.className = 'loaded';
  }, 3000);
})();
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #000000;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(20);
  -moz-transform: scale(20);
  -ms-transform: scale(20);
  transform: scale(20);
}

.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>This content is visible when the circle exapnds</h1>
 <div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div class="loader-background"></div>
 </div>
```

I have created a codepen so you can see the issue:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/rwLagV

(note, this is in Chrome)

Comment: you might give a try bluring a bit the shadow : `box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #000000, inset 0 0 5px #000000;` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQWyOz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're taking a small bitmap, then scaling it up.  If we do it the opposite way, the edges become smooth.

The original circle is rendered very small, then scaled to 20x its original size.  The jagged edges you are seeing are the original pixels!

Here's the update using box-shadow for the masking effect.  The technique is the same - render the largest state, then scale to it over 3 seconds.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.className = 'loaded';
  }, 500);
})();
```

```css
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -750px;
  right: 0;
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px #000000;
  transition: all 3s;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  /* Start off-screen */
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-background::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<h1>Updated text</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis eos modi expedita eius ab totam aspernatur fuga, rem assumenda deleniti?</p>

<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div class="loader-background"></div>
</div>
```

The values are a bit rough, and may need some tweaking to fit your use case.  A full-screen wipe will need a bigger box-shadow and ending radius than this.

Comment: Ahh, I figured it was becuase of that reason, but I should have mentioned. the reason I used the box shadow was because it has reveal the content beneath. I have updated my codepen so you can see what I mean

Comment: @r3plica Ah I see now, updated my answer to use box-shadow.